# Installing one RPM file downloaded using wget

Tags: linux, installation, rpm

I am trying to install some rpm packages in my oraacle linux. I am downloading using wget command , Like the following,

wget http://public-yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL6/addons/x86_64/getPackage/VirtualBox-4.0-4.0.22_91544_el6-1.x86_64.rpm

Can I use wget install together to download and install those packages ?

Comment: `# yum install http://public-yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL6/addons/x86_64/getPackage/VirtualBox-4.0-4.0.22_91544_el6-1.x86_64.rpm` ... i.e. yum will download and install the package, by using curl or wget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file is downloaded then you can use the below command

```
sudo alien -i rpmpackage.rpm
```